# Почему В. Набоков использует сочетание "тысяча ягод краснели"?

Tags: грамматика, стилистика, согласование

**Владимир Набоков. Памяти друга**

```
   В той чаще, где тысяча ягод
   краснели, как точки огня,
   мы двое играли; он на год,
   лишь на год был старше меня.

   Игру нам виденья внушали
   из пестрых, воинственных книг,
   и сказочно сосны шуршали,
   и мир был душист и велик.
```

Ожидаемый вариант: ***тысячи ягод краснели?*** Но, может быть, такая форма использовалась раньше для обозначения неопределенно **большого** количества? Или такое согласование возможно и сейчас?

**Для справок**

1. **Семантика** неопределенно большого количеств учитывается  также при выборе форм Т.п.:  ***тысячей и тысячью.***

**[№302572.](https://gramota.ru/spravka/vopros/302572)** Форма ***тысячью***  обозначает **неопределенно большое** количество чего-либо, в этом случае вместо согласования с последующим существительным в падеже требуется управление: человек **с тысячью** лиц, в кабинете все заполнено **тысячью** бумаг; Воздух был наполнен тысячью разных птичьих свистов (Гоголь); **тысячью** буйных и огненных голов (Л. Андреев), **тысячью** мелких уколов (Короленко).

2. **Стихотворение** написано в 1923 году. В начале 1919 года Набоков (ему было 20 лет) и его старый друг Юрий Рауш фон Траубенберг встретились в Крыму. Фон Траубенберг записался добровольцем в крымские соединения Добрармии. Набоков обещал сделать то же самое, однако в белую армию так и не вступил, а фон Траубенберг был очень скоро убит.

**ЧИТАЙТЕ ИНОГДА СТИХИ**, чтобы чувствовать время, свое и прошедшее. **Точки огня здесь настоящие!**

Жизнь Набокова сложилась так, как у многих образованных людей той эпохи. Комфортное, счастливое детство — и **"подлый треск пулеметов"** со стороны Зимнего дворца, который помешал ему записать очередное стихотворение.

Comment: мне кажется неверное согласование: либо, тысяча ягод краснела, либо, тысячи ягод краснели. Либо, краснели мы двое, играли, был на год он старше меня.

Comment: Убит он, хоть проще всё было, играл он всё в туже игру. Мне помнится: каплями крови, краснела брусника в бору.

Comment: Ожидаемый вариант: тысячи ягод краснели. Почему он так не написал? Вообще говоря, это может быть стилистика. По Розенталю разное согласование подлежащего и сказуемого возможно, но какой в этом смысл?

Comment: §184. Сказуемое при подлежащем – количественно-именном сочетании (счетном обороте) Розенталь Д.Э.,  https://vk.com/doc71820256_671560021?hash=HsSAAu6ZSSVOQ2URGwgdbc2WN6UGkULB1gDF7UepIKX&dl=aUSqlMugckMowWS9Xr3jDwkZB1o7fWZTTWMBU7R9KWw

Comment: Спасибище, *Sharon*, за вопрос!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

➊ Д. Э. Розенталь ([Сказуемое при подлежащем – количественно-именном сочетании (счетном обороте)](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL02/70091268.html)):

> **7.** При словах ***тысяча, миллион, миллиард*** сказуемое обычно согласуется по правилам согласования с подлежащими-существительными (в роде и числе), например: ***Тысяча книг поступила** в школьную библиотеку; **Миллион демонстрантов заполнил** площади и улицы столицы.*

➋ Ключевые слова в правиле: ***обычно** согласуется*.
А это никак не означает, что так должно быть всегда; возможны оба варианта согласования: *тысяча ягод краснел**и**, тысяча ягод краснел**а**.*
**Тысяча** — грамматически это существительное; счетный оборот с ним, в зависимости от "окружающих факторов", все-таки предполагает **выбор** единственного или множественного числа.

➌ Во-первых, сто лет прошло — мы не знаем, какими правилами руководствовался автор.
Во-вторых, мне кажется, что на выбор множественного числа (*тысяча ягод краснел**и***) повлияло присутствие следом идущего сравнительного оборота (*как **точки** огня*; мн. ч.): краснели, как точки огня.

➍ Барон Георгий (Юрий) Рауш фон Траубенберг был не просто другом детства писателя В. В. Набокова, он был его двоюродным братом.

> Летом 1917-го года, уже юношами, мы забавлялись тем, что каждый по очереди ложился навзничь на землю под низкую доску качелей, на которых другой мощно реял, проскальзывая над самым носом лежащего, и покусывали в затылок муравьи, а через полтора года он пал во время конной атаки в крымской степи... Может быть, я невольно подгоняю прошлое под известную стилизацию, но мне сдается теперь, что мой так рано погибший товарищ в сущности не успел выйти из воинственно-романтической майнридовой грезы, которая поглощала его настолько полнее, чем меня, во время наших, не таких уже частых и не очень долгих летних встреч (В. В. Набоков. Другие берега).

Comment: Почему-то «тысяча ягод» в стихотворении Набокова сразу притягивает внимание (мастерство поэта?),  есть что-то необыкновенное  в этих словах.    В последних же строках   еще и повтор как усиление образа: «Мне помнится: каплями крови краснела брусника в бору». Стараешься узнать  о событиях, связанных с этим стихотворением,  а это  новые впечатления и мысли.  И вот уже картина, нарисованная автором, воспринимается так свежо и ярко,  как будто и не разделяет нас время…

Comment: Большое спасибо, Римма, за внимание к стихотворению. Вы правы, наверное, нам не догадаться,  почему у Набокова «тысяча ягод».  В то же время мне кажется, что такое сочетание более поэтично, чем  привычная форма «тысячи». Нашла интересную статью, надо будет почитать:  Брайян Бойд. Владимир Набоков: вступление в биографию. Перевод с английского.  https://magazines.gorky.media/slo/2001/1/vladimir-nabokov-vstuplenie-v-biografiyu.html

Answer (score 1):

Есть [мнение](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%A2%D0%AB%D0%A1%D0%AF%D0%A7%D0%95&mode=spravka), что (по крайней мере, грамматически) *тысяча* — имя существительное, а ни разу не числительное:

*Слово тысяча управляет существительным, требуя его постановки в форме родительного падежа множественного числа, иначе говоря — грамматически ведёт себя как существительное, а не как числительное, сравним: рассказал тысяче клиентов — рассказал ста клиентам. Подробнее см. учебник Е. И. Литневской на нашем портале.*

А глаголом? Если с ним дело обстоит аналогично, то *сто клиентов ушли довольные*, но *тысяча клиентов ушла довольная*, и Набоков неправ.

(Нюанс: **одна тысяча** — числительное:

**№ 206939
*Подскажите, пожалуйста, какое окончание верное при склонении, например, существительного "монтажник" в случае: более чем о тысяче монтажникОВ? и более чем о ста монтажникАХ?***

*ОТВЕТ
Корректно: более чем о тысяче монтажниках (но: об одной тысяче монтажников), о ста монтажниках.*

https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%A2%D0%AB%D0%A1%D0%AF%D0%A7%D0%95&mode=spravka&page=3)

Comment: а что насчёт согласования глагола?

Comment: Спасибо, Егор, голос от меня. Вы правы, это грамматическое существительное, и оно обычно ведет себя как сущ., то есть всегда управляет Р .п. Но всю гармонию и однозначность нарушает форма Т.п. «тысячью», которая используется наравне с «тысячей».  И вот эти две формы могут управлять Р. п.  зависимого сущ. или согласовываться с ним в Т. п.  Получаются 4 варианта, выбирайте  что хотите. И вот вариант с тысячью ягод  (неправильное сочетание)  классики стали использовать для  обозначения неопределенно большого числа.

Comment: И возникает вопрос по Набокову:   а ему зачем откровенно неправильное согласование?  Это связано  с неопределенно большими числами или нет? Или это какой-то  художественный образ,  который мы не понимаем?

Comment: «Но всю гармонию и однозначность нарушает форма Т.п. "тысячью", которая используется наравне с "тысячей"». — Я не считаю, что она что-то «нарушает»: её наличие аналогично существованию слов «десяток» и «сотня», которые «используются наравне» с «десятью» и «стами».

Comment: «И возникает вопрос по Набокову: а ему зачем откровенно неправильное согласование?». — После которого возникает подозрение, что это просто-напросто опечатка)) Я правильно понимаю, что впервые эти стихи были напечатаны не в России?

Comment: В общем-то, самое простое объяснение.

Comment: Кстати, если бы Шарон не бегала от исторической лингвистики, считая её несусветной скукой, она бы догадалась, что «тысячью» и «тысячей» — просто два отдельных способа сделать чуть более разговорной исходную форму «тысячею»)))